# Find $x$ as $1 \lt x \lt \left(2^{32767} - 1 \right)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $x$ can't be found then prove that $2^{32767} - 1$ is a prime number.

I know that $2^{15} - 1 = 32767$

is there a correlation between $2^n - 1$  and $2^n+1(2^n - 1)$ ?

Comment: You probably mean to find a divisor of $2^{32767} - 1$. Use the fact that $2^n - 1$ is divisible by $2^d - 1$ if $d|n$.

Comment: Ok... How about 2. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

"If $x$ can't be found..." sounds like an oddly formulated problem. Assuming that you are looking to find if $2^{32767}-1$ is a prime (i.e. find if it has any divisors), consider the fact that Arthur mentioned in a comment: An integer of the form $2^n-1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is divisible by $2^d-1$ if $d \mid n$. Here's a short proof. Using the standard factorization $$x^n - y^n = (x-y) \left(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + x^{n-3}y^2 + \cdots + x y^{n-2} + y^{n-1}\right)$$ we can write
\begin{align}
2^n -1 &= (2-1) \left( 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} \cdot 1 + 2^{n-3} \cdot 1^2 + \cdots + 2 \cdot 1^{n-2} + 1^{n-1} \right)\\ &= 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-3} + \cdots +2 + 1.
\end{align}
Since $d \mid n$ we have $dk=n$ for some integer $k$. We can therefore write
\begin{align}
2^n - 1 &= 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + \cdots + 2^d + 2^{d-1} + 2^{d-2} + \cdots + 2 +1\\
&= \left( 2^{d-1} + 2^{d-2} + \cdots + 2 + 1 \right) + 2^d \left( 2^{d-1} + 2^{d-2} + \cdots + 2 + 1 \right)\\
&+ \, 2^{2d} \left( 2^{d-1} + 2^{d-2} + \cdots + 2 + 1 \right) + \cdots + 2^{d(k-1)} \left( 2^{d-1} + 2^{d-2} + \cdots + 2 + 1 \right)\\
&= \left( 2^{d-1} + 2^{d-2} + \cdots + 2 + 1 \right) \left( 1 + 2^d + 2^{2d} + \cdots + 2^{d(k-1)}\right).
\end{align}
Since $2^d-1 = 2^{d-1} + 2^{d-2} + \cdots + 2 +1$ we have that $2^d-1 \mid 2^n-1$.

The problem therefore amounts to finding integers $d \mid 32767$. We have $32767 = 7 \cdot 31 \cdot 151$. There are therefore many divisors $d$ of $32767$, so that $2^d - 1 \mid 2^{32767}-1$ and it therefore cannot be a prime number.

Comment: Using your factorization of $x^n-y^n$ you could (I feel) more simply write (using $n=dk$): $2^n-1 = 2^{dk}-1 = (2^d)^k-1^k = (2^d-1)(2^{d(k-1)}+2^{d(k-2)}+\cdots+2^d+1)$.

Comment: Did not see that. Of course, that is much simpler ;-)